# Langchain Sort document option using RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain

Tags: vector, langchain, large-language-model, pinecone

Hi I am building a chatbot that uses Vectordb to return the most up-to-date news.
how can I set the chain to retrieve the k documents vectors sorted by publish_date which is populated as a metadata field?
Here is how I define the chain:

```
    self.chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type( llm=self.llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=self.vector_db.db.as_retriever(search_type="similarity_score_threshold", search_kwargs={"score_threshold": .4, "k": 3}), chain_type_kwargs=self.chain_type_kwargs, return_source_documents=True, verbose=True )
```

Any idea how to implement a chain the rerive sorted docs befor emmit the similarity function?

Seeking docs with no sorting option